# How to fix php output

Tags: html, css

Im displaying images in a bootstrap image carousel with php.  How do I restructure the code to display the 'banner_title' under the image? The 'banner_title' is currently displayed over the image.

Ive tried using css to position the caption text.

```
$output .= '
   <img src="banner/'.$row["banner_image"].'" alt="'.$row["banner_title"].'" />
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>'.$row["banner_title"].'</h3>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried using css like this

```
$output .= '
   <img src="images/'.$row["banner_image"].'" alt="'.$row["banner_title"].'" />
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>'.$row["banner_title"].'</h3>
   </div>
  </div>
  ';
  $count = $count + 1;
 }
 return $output;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Abc LiquorMart Deals</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
h3 {color: white; font-size: 14px; float: left;}
body {background-color: black;}
h2   {color: white;}
```

Comment: You can use: add `float:left` to both image and banner, add `width:100%` to image.

Comment: And what you tried? show us code.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just the standard [Bootstrap v4 Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/), you can override the CSS `position` property to place the caption at the bottom

```css
.carousel-caption {
  position: static;
  background: grey; /* You'll want to set this to something */
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/u3tj14o0/1/)

Comment: This produced the result I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment so I can make this answer better